# Audio playback on Android Auto not working

Tags: java, android, android-auto, fmod

I developed an `Android` app that plays audio, and I need that sound to be able to be played in `Android Auto` (AA).

At the moment, my app only plays the sound through the Android device.

Testing with the `Desktop Head Unit` (AA emulator) via USB, I get sounds from apps like YouTube, or MIUI apps (Gallery or Music) to be played on the AA.

These apps don't have any kind of icon in the AA Launcher or some kind of Activity. And that's precisely what I want, just playing the audio without having to create any GUI.

Some things I've tried to implement but without success.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.car.app:app:1.2.0'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
        android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc"/>
</application>
```

**res/xml/automotive_app_desc.xml**

```
<automotiveApp>
    <uses name="media"/>
</automotiveApp>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
// Request audio focus
audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);

// FMOD API plays an audio in a Thread
FMODService.play();
```

I'm using an `FMOD` API (C++ library) to play audio, but I don't think there's a problem with that.

How can I play audio through Android Auto?

Thank you all!